# What exactly is a grid point? I am trying interpret methods for replication

Tags: raster, point, grids-graticules, sampling

These methods describe how the researcher built a model training dataset for the purpose of wetland prediction using points as training samples. My goal is to understand how these points align with the raster values, but I'm currently caught up on what a raster grid is compared to a point grid, and if a raster point grid is something different...

*"Data for training (calibrating) and evaluating the models consists of point locations classified as wetland or upland. These classifications are verified through aerial photo interpretation and field surveys. These data are stored as a point feature class within ArcGIS and are available for building and evaluating random forest models through the toolboxes developed for this project. The gradient, curvature, and local relief values for each length scale are determined for each point in the data set by overlaying the points on the rasters. Bilinear interpolation to the four nearest raster grid points is used to determine the value when the data points do not fall directly on a raster grid point (i.e., raster cell corner). Each data point then has a classification, wetland or upland, and a list of terrain attributes (gradient, plan curvature, profile curvature, and local relief at 50-, 150-, and 300-meter length scales). This table of values is then used to build the random forest model."*

...

*"For any location, the resulting random forest model can then use the terrain-attribute values at that location to calculate a probability that the location is wetland or upland. The model can thus build a new raster showing the predicted probability that a wetland will be found at each DEM grid point. Likewise, the model can predict probability of wetland occurrence for a new set of data points. The predicted probability can then be compared to the observed class (wetland or upland) to provide a test of model predictions."*

I'm looking for an interpretation of raster grid point in this method. I understand the first part (collecting training data points from known GPS locations) and the last part (the random forest model). What I don't understand is the intermediate step in which points are somehow aligned with these raster products. Is this a new point shapefile with each point at the center of every raster cell? Is there a specific workflow or tool in ArcGIS Pro that does this? The wetlands I want to predict are small in width and so I don't want those DEM products accidentally representing uplands. Any insight?